# Having Hamachi installed between 2 Windows LANs

Tags: windows, vpn, active-directory, hamachi

i had an hamachi vpn running between 2 LANs and i noticed something i couldnt explain:

1. If i instal hamachi on a Windows SBS Server, and it on a workstation belonging to another windows domain (2 independant LANs with hamachi running across the internet), i seem to be able to view the domain of the 2nd lan on some the workstations in the first domain. How is this possible if i havn't set up bridging on either machine? Is this just cosmetic in My Network places or would i be able to access the 2nd domain from a workstation in the first domain as standard?
2. On another note do connections to the SBS server via hamachi which is installed on it count as users in the sense that SBS doesnt allow more than 50/75, can i have a few extra hamachi users without the server flagging problems (would only be short term use)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed Hamachi 2.0.1.66 on my Windows7 box and I verified that the "Hamachi Network Interface" that it installs is NOT using Network Connection Sharing by default.  Perhaps you went in afterwards and enabled it?

Comment: thanks for checking, it is a bit of a strange one as didnt enable it, will remain a mystery it seems!

Comment: sounds like you have at least 3 net interfaces: hamachi, lan1, and lan2 ?   if so, do lan1 or lan2 have connection sharing enabled?  i bet there is an answer somewhere in ipconfig or netstat or tracert or some other tool like that.

Answer (score 0):

How big are your LANs?

Are you sure you want to do this with Hamachi? It is easier to setup, but I'm sure you'll get a better performance using OpenVPN.

2nd question: I'm pretty sure Hamachi doesn't affect SBS logons restriction.

Comment: our standard use of a vpn would be to allow home workers to access a sql server database, with each home worker having just the hamachi link and a voip service (not going down hamachi) running across a standard broadband service. Having it link across 2 lans was a short term one off solution with a trusted partner company.

Comment: i think that using Hamachi sounds good.  OpenVPN can be hairy to setup and Hamachi is the easiest of all the VPN solutions... even easier than regular Microsoft VPN.